# How to Combine Multiple Display Assignments Inside One Function

Tags: javascript, function, display

Inexperienced developer here. Right now my function `showTeal()` changes the display attribute of two variables and makes sure the rest remain set to `display = "none";` to make sure only certain variables are shown when the function runs. It works, but I know there must be a shorter way to do this. Any suggestions with other aspects of the pen are also greatly appreciated.

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/aubreywarpool/pen/LwxNyG

```
    function showTeal(){
      tealtray.style.display = "inline";
      tealroller.style.display = "inline";
      bg.style.animation = "tealbg 4s";
      pinkroller.style.display = "none";
      skyroller.style.display = "none";
      blueroller.style.display = "none";
      pinktray.style.display = "none";
      skytray.style.display = "none";
      bluetray.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to group things by class to access them as a group. if you ad a 'tray' and 'roller' class to your IMG tags, respectively, you can access them via a query selector

```
let rollers=document.querySelectorAll(".roller");
let trays=document.querySelectorAll(".tray");
```

then you can modify whole groups:

```
function showTeal(){
    rollers.forEach( roller => roller.style.display = "none");
    trays.forEach( tray => tray.style.display = "none");
    tealtray.style.display = "inline";
    tealroller.style.display = "inline";
    bg.style.animation = "tealbg 4s";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a JS library, such as jQuery to make these kinds of selectors and property manipulation easier. For example, with jQuery you don't need to create the groups in advance and you can select multiple queries at once:

```
function showTeal() {
    $(".rollers, .trays").hide();
    $("#tealtray, #tealroller").show();
    bg.style.animation = "tealbg 4s";
}
```

Comment: jQuery isn't giving much of an advantage here; `document.querySelectorAll('#tealtray, #tealroller').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'inline')` works just fine.